# Custom Properties for Interface Libraries

Tags: cmake, licensing

We want to add for each used library a license-file, and also a mechanism to compare licenses to detect whether they changed. So we add to each library (Boost, Qt, etc) its license file and have a checked-in copy.

We thought we can add an interface-library of our own for this, with a name of our own, and link to it the actual CMake imported library, like `Qt6::Core` or `Boost::filesystem`. But adding the license file name as a property causes an error. And finally link against our  own interface libraries only.

```
function(myNewExternal NAME)
   _myParseExternalParameters(EXTARGS ${ARGN})

   if(NOT DEFINED EXTARGS_TARGET)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "myNewExternal missing TARGET")
   endif()

   add_library(${NAME} INTERFACE)
   target_link_libraries(${NAME} INTERFACE ${EXTARGS_TARGET})

   # add property for the original files
   define_property(
      TARGET 
      PROPERTY MY_LIC_ORIGINAL
      BRIEF_DOCS "Original file name on system"
      FULL_DOCS "...")

   # add property for the checked-in files
   define_property(
      TARGET 
      PROPERTY MY_LIC_CHECKEDIN
      BRIEF_DOCS "File name checked-in git (with md5sum appended on disk)"
      FULL_DOCS "...")

   # add property for the flags (checked(c), printed(p))
   define_property(
      TARGET 
      PROPERTY MY_LIC_FLAGS
      BRIEF_DOCS "Flags for license checks or manual generation"
      FULL_DOCS "...")
endfunction()
```

Setting the property of the target, however, fails with an error

```
CMake Error at cmake/700-externals.cmake:39 (set_property):
  INTERFACE_LIBRARY targets may only have whitelisted properties.  The
  property "MY_LIC_ORIGINAL" is not allowed.
```

What am I doing wrong here and what would be the "correct" way?

Comment: It would have to be `INTERFACE_MY_LIC_ORIGINAL`

Comment: @Alex if you could make that an answer and explain the rationale, I would accept.

Answer (score 2):

Custom properties for `INTERFACE` libraries must be prefixed with `INTERFACE_`. Here is a simple CMakeLists.txt for validation:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(test NONE)

add_library(foo INTERFACE)
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY INTERFACE_CUSTOM "bar")

get_property(value TARGET foo PROPERTY INTERFACE_CUSTOM)
message(STATUS "foo.INTERFACE_CUSTOM = \"${value}\"")
```

At the command line:

```
$ cmake -S . -B build
-- foo.INTERFACE_CUSTOM = "bar"
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/alex/test/build
```

Note that custom `INTERFACE` properties don't propagate unless one of a few simple compatibility rules is defined for it. See [compatible interface properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#compatible-interface-properties) for more detail on that.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I tried prefixing my name with "INTERFACE" and it didn't work. Is this a new feature? "Whitelisted" would imply a finite list of possible identifiers to me. Or we would have a problem identifying whether an identifier is on the list in finite time

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb -- I just tried the above code with CMake 3.0.2 and it produced the same output, so no it's not a new feature. Can you produce an MRE?

Comment: I just looked through the CMake source code... version 3.19.0 removed the whitelist entirely, allowing any property on `INTERFACE` targets. As far back as 3.0.2, however, any property prefixed with `INTERFACE_` has been allowed. If you're using something before that, though... [please don't](https://alexreinking.com/blog/how-to-use-cmake-without-the-agonizing-pain-part-1.html).

Comment: Thanks Alex, I think I was maybe only changing only one of my property setters, leaving the other at the invalid name. I will recheck. Meanwhile, I will leave the checkmark!